# cookie NOT setting in browser with hapi-auth-cookie plugin

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios, hapi.js, hapi-auth-cookie

I've used hapi js for my backend and react for my frontend. The front end server is running on localhost port 3000, and the backend on 8000. So i have 2 routes like this -

`let userDetails = {
    method: "GET",
    path: "/api/user/userdata",
    config: {
        description: 'Get userdata',
        notes: 'Returns a todo item by the id passed in the path',
        tags: ['api', 'User Data'],
        cors: corsHeaders,
        auth: {
            strategy: 'restricted',
        }
    },
    handler: (request, h) => {
        return h.response(userData)
    }
}`

and

```
let createUser = {
method: "POST",
path: "/api/user/userdata",
config: {
    tags: ['api', 'User Data'],
    description: 'Upload User data to the db',
    cors: corsHeaders,
},
handler: async (request, h) => {

    const { username, emailId, password } = request.payload
    request.cookieAuth.set({ username })
    return h.response('cookie created!')

}
```

}

now the 'post' route sets the cookie by  request.cookieAuth.set({ username }),
so when i posted through postman application, it's setting the cookie in postman and the get route sends the data without any problem. But in browser, the cookie is'nt being set.

i'm using hapi-auth-cookie plugin and the registration is done like this -

```
await server.register(HapiAuthCookie)

server.auth.strategy('restricted', 'cookie',{
    password: 'AudhASp342SID3acdh83CDASHciAS93rashdiva34a',
    cookie: 'session',
    isSecure: false,
    ttl: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
})
```

someone please help

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same problem.